# Help with printer format settings

Tags: gimp, print-production

I don't know where else to turn with my problem, so I'll try here.
I have an Epson ET-2710 and it's working fine... as long as I only print in the A4 format.
I've told the printer in the settings to print 10x15cm (4x6 inches) but for some reason the picture I'm trying to print is offset a lot and not even in the correct orientation. Even worse, when I try to change the orientation from vertical to landscape the picutre is not even on paper anymore.

Here are a few screenshots of my problem (Currently trying to print a scanned Magic card to calibrate my printer so I can make my own card game). Screenshots were too big to be posted here it seems, so here's a link to imgur with my problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wu8On.jpg

Comment: I'm afraid this may be *far too* localized and all anyone can do is guess, unless they have the exact same printer with the exact same OS.

Comment: That's sort of my last hope to fix this issue :(

Comment: Why are you printing from GIMP?  Don't do that.  Try exporting your image as PNG/JPEG and just print it using Windows built in photo viewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this solves your problem.

[GIMP Printing Problem](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Basic-print-issues-orientation-paper-size-etc)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.